# sizeToFit with maximum width

Tags: ios, swift, label, sizetofit

I am trying to programmatically manipulate a `UILabel` so that it has a dynamic width.

I found that using `sizeToFit()` does this exact behavior.
Now as this label becomes my `navigationItem.titleView`. I want it to have a maximum size, which can't be extended.

It is important to fit 2 `barButtonItems` in the `navigationItem`.
For instance: a `backBarButton` on the left, an `addButton` on the right.

Is there a way to change the `sizeToFit()` method?

Comment: you can calculate width as per position & size of both button

Comment: Does the `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` property of `UILabel` help?

Comment: Thanks and @paulvs I have set a fixed maxSize and used adjustFontSizeToFitWidth!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sizeThatFits:` see docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/sizeThatFits:).

You have to specify a CGSize that you want to fit in.

Answer (score 1):

to set maximum width use `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` than set the maximum size like that `bounds.width - 120`

for example:

```
    yourLabel.sizeToFit()
    yourLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    yourLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = bounds.width - 120
```